# convert long dataset to wide dataset using R

Tags: r, reshape2

I'd appreciate some assistance in what R code to use in the following situation:

This is the top 11 rows of the dataset:

```
Sa1_main11  Sa1_main11_2
20401106101 20401106101 -
20401106101 21105128609 -
20401106101 21105128653
20601110501 20601110501
20601110501 20601110530
20601110501 20601110531
20601110501 20601110532
20601110501 20601110533
20601110501 20601110534
20601110501 20601110614
20601110502 20601110502
```

SA1s are a geographical unit used by the Australian Bureau of Statistics.

This file is a list of what SA1 are contiguous - column 1 is the base SA1, and the second column is the SA1 that adjoins the first SA1.

For example, take the first 3 rows

- 20401106101 adjoins itself
- 21105128609 adjoins 20401106101
- 21105128653 adjoins 20401106101

What I need to do is to produce a dataset where the first line is of the format

```
20401106101  21105128609  21105128653
```

I've tried `reshape2` package, but the lack of row labels (which would all be identical) makes that not possible for me.

Edit - here is a link to what the data looks like

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tigqdevybskm1bs/Original.JPG

here is a link to what the top 3 rows should look like

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2l36mry9ibfnfq/Destination.JPG

Comment: I'm not sure what the desired result is. Maybe `table(DF)`?

Comment: If you could provide the complete desired output based on the sample data, this would be very helpful.

Comment: Have now included links to pictures of larger original and output example.  Also tried table() - that produces a very large matrix with each SA1 as a row and column, with what looks like a zero in each cell.

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of data in questions. Copy the data into the question and format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works: (`dat` is the dataset)

```
 library(reshape2)
 dat$indx <- with(dat, ave(seq_along(Sa1_main11), Sa1_main11, FUN=seq_along))
 dcast(dat, Sa1_main11~indx, value.var="Sa1_main11_2")
 #     Sa1_main11           1           2           3           4           5
 #1 20401106101 20401106101 21105128609 21105128653          NA          NA
 #2 20601110501 20601110501 20601110530 20601110531 20601110532 20601110533
 #3 20601110502 20601110502          NA          NA          NA          NA
 #           6           7
 #1          NA          NA
 #2 20601110534 20601110614
 #3          NA          NA
```

Comment: Thanks Roland and akrun for your assistance. Both solutions resulted in identical output; akrun's solution was quite a bit quicker to run (although with only 69k rows in the input dataset, that wasn't much of an issue for me.  I had to modify the output of both solutions in excel to remove the NAs, and I haven't yet tested whether that is going to be an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `split` might help you:

```
split(DF[,2], DF[,1]) 

#$`20401106101`
#[1] 20401106101 21105128609 21105128653
#
#$`20601110501`
#[1] 20601110501 20601110530 20601110531 20601110532 20601110533 20601110534 20601110614
#
#$`20601110502`
#[1] 20601110502
```

It's unclear what you intend to do with the data. Neither data.frames nor matrices can hold rows of different length. So replicating the exact result is a bit complicated (and not very useful). Anyway, this would come close:

```
res <- split(DF[,2], DF[,1]) 
res <- lapply(res, function(x) {
  length(x) <- max(sapply(res, length))
  x
  })

do.call(rbind, res)
#                   [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]        #[,7]
#20401106101 20401106101 21105128609 21105128653          NA          NA          NA          NA
#20601110501 20601110501 20601110530 20601110531 20601110532 20601110533 20601110534 20601110614
#20601110502 20601110502          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
```

Comment: About the comment about rows of different length; the output file will be used with HLM software. I'll be doing a hierarchical linear model with two levels, where contiguity constraints are included. HLM software requires the file with the contiguity data to be in this format.